# Exception follows-org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load source type: com.cloudera.flume

Tags: linux, hadoop, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

I am trying to do twitter analysis using Flume. For getting the tweets from the twitter i have set all the required params (consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken and accessTokenSecret) in the flume.conf files .

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken =  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop,opensource,iamsrk,onairwithaib,ihrithik
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/elections/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Classpath in flume-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle 
FLUME_CLASSPATH="home/nick/Downloads/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/lib/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

When I run flume agent

```
`apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/bin$`  ./flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -c conf -f ../conf/twitter.conf

    INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source Twitter, type com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
15/10/30 01:44:19 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load source type: com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource, class: com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
    at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.getClass(DefaultSourceFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:322)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:97)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.getClass(DefaultSourceFactory.java:67)
    ... 11 more
```

can anyone say why this error is thrown when i set the flume source.jar already.Please help me out on this .

Answer (score 0):

flume configuration path needs to be mentioned properly  instead of ../conf/twitter.conf. Try to point the conf to right path in the parameter and execute it.